# How do I call a method in X component and then render component Y on react button click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, react-component

I am new to react and need to add a button to UI, where on button click in component A, firstly on button click, the method in component X will be called which creates a new DB entry and returns ID, and then I need to display that ID in a popup, which means I need to render a new Competent ,say Y, which will display that ID in popup.How can I achieve that?

I know adding a button and making a getting result from component X, but then how can I render them in component Y, since there is no such action associated with Button?

Comment: so in this case does the component  X and Y child component to A?

Comment: No, i dont see any relation. Component A is where I add button, and Component X a store, where I will make api call, and component Y is like a popup container.All are different

Comment: You can use react-redux to do this.